# SQL count row equal to column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, count

Here is my table:

```
+--------+---------------------+
| roomNo |        date         |
+--------+---------------------+
|      1 | 2017-05-17 16:05:00 |
|      1 | 2017-05-17 15:05:00 |
|      2 | 2019-05-20 12:30:00 |
|      2 | 2019-05-15 10:30:00 |
|      2 | 2019-05-14 08:00:00 |
+--------+---------------------+
```

I want to get the day where the room is used at least once and which day(s) had the most operations in it and how many times, in the current year. I don't know how to compare the dates.

The expected result would be something like :

```
+--------+------------+------------+
| roomNo |    date    | operations |
+--------+------------+------------+
|      2 | 2019-05-20 |          3 |
+--------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Comment: How do your specified results show "the days where the room is used at least once"?

Comment: Why isn't roomNo 1 returned? And roomNo 2 had only 1 operation 2019-05-20, not 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use MySQL `DATE` function to lop off times from DATETIME and TIMESTAMP columns. Or we could use MySQL `DATE_FORMAT` function, to return just year, month day.

We can use an aggregate function like `COUNT` or `SUM` in a query with `GROUP BY` to get counts by room and day.

If "current year" means from Jan 1 thru Dec 31, we can use expression to derive date values of '2019-01-01' and '2020-01-01', and do a comparison of the `date` column to those values in the WHERE clause.

As a start, consider this:

```
SELECT t.roomno       
     , DATE(t.date)  AS date_
     , COUNT(*)      AS cnt_
  FROM mytable t
 WHERE t.date >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-01-01') + INTERVAL 0 YEAR
   AND t.date  < DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-01-01') + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
 GROUP
    BY t.roomno
     , DATE(t.date)
 ORDER
    BY t.roomno
     , cnt_  DESC
```

If the goal is to just return one of the rooms that has the highest number of uses, we could use a LIMIT clause, and order by the highest count to lowest,

```
 ORDER
    BY cnt_  DESC
     , t.roomno
 LIMIT 1
```

If the results are more complex than that, we can omit the LIMIT clause, and use the result from that query as an inline view in an outer query.

With MySQL 8.0, we can use common table expression (CTE) and window/analytic functions, to get more elaborate results.